# Firefox rendering my images as the wrong color - but fine in other browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

I have built a website however I am having problems with the png's in firefox as it is rendering the images as the wrong color.  When I inspect the element in dev tool on firefox the images display as the right color which is what I don't understand.

Could someone help

www.forestroad.co.uk

Comment: remove this line from your code!!!! filter: invert(100%);

Answer (score 1):

You just need to comment this line on this line on .forest-road class:

```
.forest-road {
    height: auto;
   color: #FFF;
    max-width: 75%;
    /*filter: invert(100%); Comment this line!!!! :) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have use `filter` property in your css. that causing this effect in the firefox.try to change the value of `filter: invert(100%);` to something different and you will see color change of your images in firefox.If you will remove `filter`property than image will look same in every browser.